# Null pointer Exception in Imageview.getDrawingCache on Secondtime

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, drawingcache

```
            View vvv=mViewFlipper.getCurrentView();             
            RelativeLayout rrr=(RelativeLayout)vvv;
            ImageView img=(ImageView) rrr.getChildAt(0);
            img.setRotation(90); 

            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            img.buildDrawingCache();                
            Bitmap bitmap =img.getDrawingCache();             
            img.destroyDrawingCache();
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
            BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBitmap); 
            rrr.removeViewAt(0);
            ImageView img_new=new ImageView(ImageSlideShow.this);
            img_new.setImageDrawable(bmd);
            img_new.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
            rrr.addView(img_new, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I have Used Above code for Image rotating in `ViewFlipper`.
First time it is executed but second time it return `NullPointerException`...
**Error line:**

```
Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `img`?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());

Comment: Is your ImageView is dynamic or avalible in your xml file??

Comment: No it's not dynamic it is in xml file

Comment: Have you done ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(your img id); ?

Comment: you dont need drawing cache at all, use getDrawable instead

Comment: View vvv=mViewFlipper.getCurrentView();    
    RelativeLayout rrr=(RelativeLayout)vvv;
    ImageView img=(ImageView) rrr.getChildAt(0);

Comment: But for rotating Image it need Bitmap ...
So i have to convert first it Imageview to Bitmap ...
getDrawable() not return Bitmap

Comment: you can use RotateDrawable or use scaleType set to "matrix" and rotete the matrix used to draw the Drawable

Comment: ok it seems that RotateDrawable can only be used from xml resources so the second option is your friend, use rotated matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi use this code and hopefully this works

basically your image view is null so first inintiallise it

```
ImageView img= new ImageView();
img=(ImageView) rrr.getChildAt(0);
        img.setRotation(90); 

img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        img.buildDrawingCache(); 
if(img.isDrawingCacheEnabled()){               
        Bitmap bitmap =img.getDrawingCache(true);             
}img.destroyDrawingCache();
        img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                bao);

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBitmap); 
        rrr.removeViewAt(0);
        ImageView img_new=new ImageView(ImageSlideShow.this);
        img_new.setImageDrawable(bmd);
        img_new.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        rrr.addView(img_new, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Your Code Give...
04-23 12:12:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11038): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap

Comment: It's same as above ...first time working and second time it return NULL in Bitmap bitmap =img.getDrawingCache();

Comment: java file code i have given that above...and xml file is just ViewFlipper >RelativeLayout>ImageView

Comment: debug at imageview what you are getting log it because i use this  its working for me

Comment: post your full logcat so i can check

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:497)
at com.example.snaprecipe.ImageSlideShow$3.onClick(ImageSlideShow.java:106)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

Comment: well you know how to debug ?? debug it and find which variable is null

Comment: your imageview is null thats why is throwing nullpointer error

Comment: i checked your code ....it's same give me same error.But also second time imageview not return null but image.getDrawingCache(true); return null.........

Comment: well its working in my phone  can you tell me what you are doing and crashing app ??

Comment: Ya it also Working for me using his code
ImageView img=(ImageView) rrr.getChildAt(0);   
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
                matrix.set(img.getImageMatrix());
                matrix.postRotate(90, img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
                img.setImageMatrix(matrix);

Comment: hey bro please download code from link  https://www.dropbox.com/s/olux0i9etre6qhw/ViewFliperDemoWithRotation24_04_2014.zip

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution For this problem

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) rrr.getChildAt(0);            
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
                matrix.set(img.getImageMatrix());
                matrix.postRotate(90, img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
                img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

above code complete working for image rotation and you must set android:scaleType="matrix" in your imageview.